# pandas удалить последний символ в колонке по условию в другой колонке

Tags: python, pandas

В таблице есть артикулы art_str длиной 5 (68965) и 6 (689621) символов, это строки. Если символов 6, то нужно , удалить последний символ (1), чтобы сократить до 5 символов (68962)
Тут я сделал доп колонку len_new_art с длиной символов, по ней нужно привести все к 5 символам.

Comment: пример данных должен быть в вопросе

Answer (score 2):

не нужно изобретать велосипед

```
df["art_str"] = df["art_str"].str[:5]
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую! )